# specific meaning of strchrnul in man page

Tags: c++, c

> The strchrnul() function is like strchr() except that if c is not
>          found in s, then it returns a pointer to the null byte at the end of
>          s, rather than NULL.

[this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html#top_of_page) is DESCRIPTION of strchrnual in man page. I don't understand the specific meaning of `the null byte at the end of s`.

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty straightforward, it return's the address of the first '\0' which is usually the last byte of the c-string.

Comment: @n0p why are you posting an answer as a comment rather than as an answer?

Comment: @JesperJuhl What's wrong with doing so?

Comment: @n0p just the fact that you won't get any credit for answering the question and it sort of goes against the format of the site. Answers should be posted as answers, comments are for (well) *comments*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am not looking into getting credits (ok, at least for answers to questions like this) and everyone is free to post his/her own answer. Will delete my comment then.

Comment: @n0p: _"What's wrong with doing so?"_. Many, many things. It's not just about getting credit - SO's entire model is built around peer review, and by posting your answer as a comment, you bypass the peer review system. Answers go in the answer section; that's why there's an answer section!

Comment: Flag the comment. Write your own answer. This starts to take too much attention from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strchr()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.2) function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a character within a string, or a null pointer if the character is not in the string. Thus, you must not dereference the return value of `strchr()` without first checking to see if it is a null pointer to avoid undefined behavior.

The [`strchrnul()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchrnul) function is different from `strchr()` in a couple of ways. First, while `strchr()` is a Standard Library function, `strchrnul()` is not, but is instead a GNU extension since glibc 2.1.1. You may need to define the feature test macro `_GNU_SOURCE` in order to enable this function. Second, while `strchrnul()` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character in the string, a pointer to the null terminator `\0` is returned if the character is not in the string. Thus it is always safe to dereference the return value from `strchrnul()`. If the character does not occur in the string, the return value points to the end of the string (the terminating null byte), and dereferencing this pointer results in a value of `0`. Presumably the function `strchrnul()` gets its name because the function returns either a pointer to the sought character or a pointer to the null byte.

About the phrase "terminating null byte": a C string is an array of `char`s with the special property that the last `char` in the string is the null byte. Of course, a `char` is guaranteed to have a width of one byte in C. The null byte is represented by the character literal `'\0'`, but is also sometimes called the null terminator, or the NUL terminator (though this name is really specific to the encoding, but does exist in ASCII and EBCDIC). The Standard says that:

> C11 §5.2.1 2
>   A byte with all bits set to 0, called the *null
>   character*, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is
>   used to terminate a character string.

Answer (score 0):

this function is very handy to kick out the trailing \n
from the input string:

```
    *strchrnul(input_string,'\n') = '\0';
```

if there is a \n in string, function generates pointer to that character.
if there is no \n in string, function generates pointer to string
ending \0, and putting \0 over \0 is ok.
(apparently this assumes that there is no more than one \n in the string,
i.e. this works for fgets-style strings which end with \n.)